# How can I tell regex not to ignore nested matches?

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to find all shortcode tag pairs within the below string but all the shortcode tag pairs that are nested within other shortcodes tag pairs are ignored when I use this regex pattern

```
\[sc(.*?)-(.*?) var=`(.*?)`\]((.|\r\n)*?)\[\/sc\1-\2\]
```

here's the string im searching through

```
<ul>
  [sc1-s-foreach var=`Trip/Day 1`]
  <li><b>Event</b>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <b>What:</b> [sc1-s-foreach-g var=`What`][/sc1-s-foreach-g]
      </li>
      <li>
        <b>How:</b> [sc1-s-foreach-g var=`How`][/sc1-s-foreach-g]
      </li>
      <li>
        <b>When:</b> [sc1-s-foreach-g var=`When`][/sc1-s-foreach-g]
      </li>
      <li>
        <b>Where:</b> [sc1-s-foreach-g var=`Where`][/sc1-s-foreach-g]
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  [/sc1-s-foreach]
</ul>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Regex is not well-suited to this sort of task of dealing with HTML or recursive structures, but even if you are stuck with regex, providing some details about the regex flavor/environment you're using would be helpful. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Please stop using `(.|\r\n)*?`, this is the most misfortunate regex construct. `.` matches any char, use it with the right modifier like `s` or `m`.

Comment: I'm not sure what flavor/environments means but if your asking what programming language I'm using it with it's PHP. I'm not sure why someone downvoted my question, I'd really appreciate a useful answer.

Comment: You do understand that `foreach var=` is not the same as `foreach-g var=` ? That means there is no _nesting_. Is that what you refer to ?

Comment: Hi sIn at no point did I claim that or imply that `foreach var=` and `foreach-g var=` are the same, how ever please search the string i provided with the regex patern i provided with and without the parent shortcode tag pair and you will see the regex patern is general enough to match them all

Comment: For your sample data you could use backreferences to what was captured in `$1` and `$2` for the closing tag [like in this demo](https://regex101.com/r/KmbpXb/1). Not sure if this works for your real data.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this

```
\[sc(.*?)-(.*?)(?:-.*?)?[ ]var=`(.*?)`\]((?:(?!\[\/sc\1-\2(?:-.*?)?\])[\S\s])*?)\[\/sc\1-\2\]
```

https://regex101.com/r/4Tv2Js/1

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer from Quora that says

You will need to use recursion. Not all languages have recursion in their regular expression implementation.

For example in PHP you could use the following regular expression to match the text inside parenthesis including nested parentheses:

```
    \(([^()]|(?R))*\)
```

- Match a starting parenthesis `\(`
- Match any amount of:

  - a character that is not a parenthesis `[^()]`
  - the entire regular expression `(?R)`
- Match an ending parenthesis `\)`

Comment: In the text book it's `\((?:[^()]++|(?R))*\)` not what you show which is wrong and misinformed. Your question Is not about recursion since there is no _nesting_ in your sample. I thought I told you that already.

Comment: To repeat myself - "please search the string i provided with the regex patern i provided with and without the parent shortcode tag pair and you will see the regex patern is general enough to match them all "

Comment: It is _NOT_ general, it is _SPECIFIC_ matches.  This part `\[sc(.*?)-(.*?)`  controls this part `sc\1-\2\]` It may match with `(.*?)-(.*?)` but it only matches _ONE_ closure with the backreference `\1-\2`

Comment: sorry no offence (and i appreciate your help) but i dont have a lot of energy to debate this other than the following:
"please search the string i provided with the regex patern i provided (the "\r" can be removed) with (as seen here https://regex101.com/r/AAEQVh/1/)  and without  (as seen here https://regex101.com/r/KKVIGX/2) the parent shortcode tag pair and you will see the regex patern is general enough to match them all "

Comment: The original regex you posted _DOES_ match them all, but it matches them _INDIVIDUALLY_, i.e. one at a time, not all at once. You must get past that reality to decide your next step. It's clear as day what it does, you however just can't see it. No offence, I wish you well !!